# What's the secret info able to be garnered from the 1.7 screenshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Notch tweeted a couple of pictures a while ago, one of the 1.7 changelog blurred, one of a picture at night with a yellow dot at the left, which he then said that he fixed a bug and reposted the picture with the yellow dot gone.

Notch said that some info from v1.7 can be acquired from these pictures and said that someone has figured it out already. What is it?

Comment: However this question will soon expire when 1.7 comes out.

Comment: @xfs: It will still be accurate and relevant, just not as interesting. If it came out without me knowing, I'd still want to go back and find out what it was.

Comment: awww, I still say that this is on-topic. I'm not asking just about what will be in v1.7; I'm asking about what's hidden in the picture. That'll never change, and I think that in the future more people may be interested in how it's hidden in the pictures/how people found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course a combination of guesswork and snooping so may not be 100% accurate:

A redditor downloaded eclipse and compared letters on tabs to match the half letter on each of Notch's tabs. He came up with the following: 
[image]

Here is the original image for comparison: 
[image]

Which as Mark Trapp says fits with the Minecraft wiki

Source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/hzqg7/i_think_i_figured_out_the_secret_in_the_changelog/)